# Sequence represented by fruits

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

A person is confused about how a mathematical sequence works, to explain to her, her teacher does not use numbers and turns into sets of fruits. Which sequence is being represented by the teacher?

a. Farey Sequence
b. Sequence of prime numbers
c. Sequence of odd numbers
d. Fibonacci sequence 
e. None of the previous

Can anyone help me with the interpretation of this question? I can see ways to represent all the strings (maybe not Farey's) using fruits (which I think represent natural numbers).

[Source](https://www.amazon.com.br/Desaf%C3%ADos-matem%C3%A1ticos-Est%C3%ADmulos-Matem%C3%A1ticos-Spanish-ebook/dp/B01DJLLBFE/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=matematic+children&qid=1609713168&sr=8-1)

Comment: This seems pretty opinion-based to me - all of these sequences could probably be represented by fruits if one was creative enough.

Comment: Is it possible that this question originates in a language other than English? Because if "fruits" could mean "offspring" then it's _definitely_ the Fibonacci sequence, which was originally introduced in the context of a problem about rabbits breeding.

Comment: Looking at the source, it definitely _does_ originate in a language other than English.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I didn't really know that second meaning. Thanks!

Comment: In that case it probably isn't one. (In English, "fruit" can rather archaically mean "offspring", but you'd never ever say "fruits" with that meaning. And if whatever Portuguese word has been rendered here as "fruits" doesn't have that meaning, it's irrelevant anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is

> d. Fibonacci Sequence

Reasoning

> The Fibonacci sequence often appears in nature.
>  For example, on the majority of pineapples, counting rows in three different directions yields a Fibonacci number, see image below
>  [image]
>  [image source](https://craftofcoding.wordpress.com/2020/05/28/fibonacci-and-pineapples/)